# How to stop Adobe Reader to modify pdf's

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

After reading pdf files with Adobe Acrobat Reader v.2015.017.20053 files get modified. How to stop that.

Comment: Does this happen with any PDF, or just with some specific files?

Comment: ye, with all... but it was... it f***d me so, that I started to use SumatraPortable and in parallel tweeking Adobe and somehow I stopped, probably when unchecked 'Save Settings / Automatically save ... every...' and now I can't reproduce and feel silly - so do not know - remove question or what...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How do I stop Adobe Reader modifying files?

1. Menu "Edit" > "Preferences" (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>).
2. In the section "Categories" click "Documents".
3. In the section "Open Settings" disable (uncheck) "Restore last view settings when reopening documents".
4. Click OK.

   [image]

Comment: thanks, but not sure how that's related to the problem

Comment: When you enable  "Restore last view settings when reopening documents" it modifies the pdf file on exit to add a "bookmark" of where you were in the file.